# Moderate email without notifying sender Office365

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I know i can forward emails for approval, can this be transparent so if rejected the sender is not notify'd?  Unorthodox request I know, strange business requirement.

Comment: By Office 365, I assume you mean Exchange Online and not Outlook from Office 365 Pro Plus, correct?

Comment: Could you explain the business requirement s little further?  I think a transport rule will do what you need easy peasy.